Why does integral $j$-invariant imply good potential reduction
Over a local field, is there a slick proof for if $j$-invariant is integral then the inertia group action has finite image?
It's not clear how to use integralness of $j$ invariant to say anything about the tate representation.

With an integral $j$-invariant and over a suitable (finite) field extension, you can construct an integral model of the elliptic curve with good reduction. Hence the image of a finite index subgroup of the inertia group is trivial, hence the image of inertia is finite. This is done very well in Silverman, if I recall correctly.

Is there anything else you wanted to add to your question like what is specifically unclear or what you may have already noticed?

@Aphelli I wanted to know why you can built a model with good reduction. I tried to reduce the question to the finite image :)

Ah. Well, I fear you’ve managed to reduce the question to a harder problem… there may be non-circular arguments working in this way, but building the actual model with the actual equation might be the simplest approach. I think this is done in Silverman, and I vaguely recall that there’s a simple explicit equation working in most cases (if the residual $j$-invariant isn’t $0$ or $1728$), but I’m unsure about the general case.

All of what follows is done (probably in a better way) in the relevant chapter of Silverman’s standard Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.

Lemma: let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a non-Archimedean local field $K$ with mixed characteristic such that $E[12]$ is defined over $K$. Then (the minimal Weierstrass equation of) $E$ has either good or multiplicative reduction, depending on whether its $j$-invariant is integral or not.
Proof: Let $k$ be the residue field with characteristic $p$. Assume that $E$ has additive reduction. Then you have the exact sequences $$0 \rightarrow E^0(K) \rightarrow E(K) \rightarrow \Gamma \rightarrow 0,$$ $$0 \rightarrow E^1(K) \rightarrow E^0(K) \rightarrow E^{sm}(k) \rightarrow 0,$$ where $E^1(K)$ is a pro-$p$-group, $|\Gamma| \leq 4$ and $E^{sm}(k) \simeq \mathbb{A}^1(k) = k$ is a $p$-group (see Silverman I).
It follows that $E(K)$ does not contain a copy of $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^2$, a contradiction.
If $j(E)$ is non-integral, then $E$ cannot have good reduction so it has multiplicative reduction. Conversely, if $E$ has multiplicative reduction, a direct look at its minimal model shows that its $j$-invariant is non-integral.

So assume that $E/K$ has an integral $j$-invariant and let $L/K$ be a finite extension such that all the $12$-torsion of $E$ is contained in $E(L)$.
Then $E/L$ has good or multiplicative reduction depending on the integrality of $j(E)$. Thus $E/L$ has good reduction and the inertia group of $L$ acts trivially on (prime-to-residue-characteristic) torsion, and the conclusion follows.
